# My State value is not Changing ,when button is pressed

Tags: react-native

```
onButtonPress = () => {
  min = 1000;
  max = 9999;
  randomotp = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
  console.log(Math.round(randomotp));
  this.setState({
    otpfield:'#48A23A'
   });
   console.log('result',this.state.otpfield);
  }
}
```

I have been executing this function in the Button on click , but the corresponding (i,e Otpfield) value is not changing

Comment: Did you try to console.log the otpfield value in setState's callback?
`this.setState({
   otpfield:'#48A23A'
 }, () => console.log('result',this.state.otpfield));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state will not change. onButtonPress function must finish executing first before changing the state.

use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method to check if the state changed

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 console.log('result',this.state.otpfield);
 //new State
 console.log('result',prevState.otpfield);
// prev State
}
```

Comment: is componentDidUpdate called only when components props change or also when  inner state change (after setstate ) ?

Comment: i think you mean componentWillReceiveProps. 

componentDidUpdate . can be called , both in changing props and state.

Answer (score 2):

React does not update the state immediately, it's an asynchronous operation. Therefore your `console.log()` call is invoked too fast and the state is not yet changed.

Use the "afterUpdated" callback instead (second parameter of the [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method):

```
this.setState(
    {property: true},
    () => console.log(this.state.property)
);
```